# Airflow multiple runs of different task branches

Tags: airflow, branch

Lets assume we have 2 tasks as airflow operators: `task_1` and `task_2`. We want to skip `task_1` on Mondays and run both tasks on the rest of the days. In addition we also want to re-run both tasks on monday at a later time.

**Example of a monday run:**

Run 1: `task_2`

Run 2: `task_1` -> `task_2`

**Example of rest of week runs:**

Run 1: `task_1` -> `task_2`

So on mondays first task gets skipped and in a later second run both tasks run, whereas on all other days both tasks run as usual.

We already looked at the `BranchDayOfWeekOperator()` (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/weekday.html) but this does not solve the second re-run issue on mondays.

Can you help us with the re-run issue ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `BranchDayOfWeekOperator` you can skip `task_1` on Monday, and execute it on other days, and set the branch and the `task_1` as upstream for `task_2` and set its trigger rule to `ONE_SUCCESS` in order to execute it for the two branchs:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.weekday import BranchDayOfWeekOperator, WeekDay


with DAG(
    'dag',
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 1),
) as dag:
    branch = BranchDayOfWeekOperator(
        task_id="skip_monday",
        follow_task_ids_if_true="task_2",
        follow_task_ids_if_false="task_1",
        week_day={WeekDay.MONDAY},
    )
    task_1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_1")
    task_2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task_2", trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS)
    branch >> [task_1, task_2]
    task_1 >> task_2
```

But you need to know that this operator use the `start date` by default, so if you want to skip Monday runs and not the runs executed on Monday (backfill or cleared runs), you need to add the argument `use_task_logical_date=True`.

> In addition we also want to re-run both tasks on Monday at a later time.

if you want to run it later, you can run it manually using Airlfow UI, and activating `Ignore All Deps`
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have the following questions: after declaring the branching logic `branch >> [task_1, task_2]` you again declare `task_1 >> task_2`. Wouldn't this retrigger task_1 followed by Task_2 any way? Do you know of a way where we can r-run the dag on mondays with both tasks automatically again without using the UI?